# TwitchTV Undefined offset

Tags: php

So I have read all up on the TwitchTV API, searched all of the net for a answer, tried multiple codes, and I still can't get this to work.

What is happening is when the stream in the $channel variable in not online, the page ALWAYS returns a error of

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/user/public_html/livestreamstatus.php on line 13

. I need to know how to get rid of this and just display the word "OFFLINE"

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    $channel = "gamespot";

    $json_file = @file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel={$channel}", 0, null, null);
    $json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

    if ($json_array[0]['name'] == "live_user_{$channel}") {
        $channelTitle = $json_array[0]['channel']['title'];
        $title = $json_array[0]['channel']['status'];

?>
    ONLINE
<br />

<?php

    } else {

?>
    OFFLINE
<?php

    }

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried var_dump($json_array) to see what data you're actually getting?

Comment: Yes, I get array(0) { }. But when the stream is live then it return actual info inside of the { }

Comment: if you just want to ignore the Notice, then turn off error reporting __error_reporting(0);__ or if you want to use the notice to say offline then POSSIBLY use try{}catch(Exception $e){}

Comment: error reporting error_reporting(0); didn't work for. Unless I did it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want is to check if that even exists, so ask php to check for you, before calling to it.

```
<?php
$channel = "gamespot";

$json_file = @file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.json?channel={$channel}", 0, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);

if( array_key_exists( '0',       $json_array )
 && array_key_exists( 'channel', $json_array[0] )
 && $json_array[0]['name'] == "live_user_{$channel}" )
{
    $channelTitle = $json_array[0]['channel']['title'];
    $title        = $json_array[0]['channel']['status'];

    printf('Online');
}
else
{
    printf('Offline');
}

?>
```